# If $H \triangleleft G$, $H$ is cyclic, $G/H$ is cyclic prove that $G$ is generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've had the problem from the title on a test a few days ago, and I'd like to check whether my proof is correct because I'm kind of skeptic because of how complicated it ended up being.

So, first we know that $H \triangleleft G$ meaning:

$$(1) \quad (\forall g) \quad gHg^{-1} \subset H$$
Since we also know that $H$ is cyclic that means that every element in $H$ can be represented as some power of the generator, let's call it $\alpha$:
$$(\forall h \in H) \quad h = \alpha^{k} \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

If we rewrite $(1)$ as:
$$(\forall g \in G)(\forall h \in H) \quad ghg^{-1} \in H$$ we get:
$$\quad g\alpha^{k}g^{-1} \in H \text{ but since that's also in }H \text{ we get}$$
$$(2) \quad g\alpha^{k}g^{-1} = \alpha^{s} \text{ for some } s\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now we're going to use the fact that $G/H = \big\{ gH :g\in G \big\}$ is also cyclic, meaning:
$$(\forall g \in G) \quad gH = \beta^{m} \text{ for some } m \in \mathbb{Z}$$ 
which leads us to
$$(3) \quad (\forall g \in G) \quad g\alpha^{n}=\beta^{m}$$

By doing some multiplication on $(2)$ and $(3)$ I got:
$$\text{From (2) } \quad g\alpha^kg^{-1} = \alpha^s \quad \big/ \cdot g(\alpha^k)^{-1} \Rightarrow 
\\g = \alpha^sg(\alpha^k)^{-1}$$
$$\text{From (3) } \quad g\alpha^n = \beta^m \quad \big/\cdot(\alpha^n)^{-1} \Rightarrow
\\ g = \beta^m(\alpha^n)^{-1}$$

Equating the two gives me:

$$\cdot (\alpha^s)^{-1}\big/\quad\alpha^sg(\alpha^k)^{-1} = \beta^m(\alpha^n)^{-1} \quad \big/\cdot \alpha^k \Rightarrow
\\g = (\alpha^s)^{-1}\beta^m(\alpha^n)^{-1}\alpha^{k}$$
And since that applies $(\forall g \in G)$ it means that $G$ is generated by two elements ($\alpha$ and $\beta$).

Does this seem correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of doing a number with a huge amount of spaces, just include `\tag{#}` in the markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made it very complicated. Actually it can be done much easier. Let $H=\langle h\rangle$ and  $G/H=\langle xH\rangle$. If $g\in G$ then $g$ belongs to a left coset of $H$, hence there is some $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ for which $g\in x^iH$. It means $g$ can be written in the form $x^ik$ when $k\in H$. There is some $j\in\mathbb{Z}$ for which $h^j=k$. Then $g=x^ih^j\in\langle h,x\rangle$.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. 
But is it correct even though it's complicated? :)

Comment: To be honest I'm a bit confused at what you mean by $gH=\beta^m$. The quotient group is a group of cosets, it can't be generated by an element of $G$. Perhaps you mean $gH=\beta^mH$?

Comment: The notation that I've used is a little weird, I'll admit. But by that I meant that any coset can be generated by some element $\beta$ in the quotient group. I'm not sure though whether I can use the multiplicative notation for that? That might be the mistake.

Comment: Well, then there is a problem in the next line. If $\beta$ is in the quotient group then it is a coset. Hence you can't write $g\alpha^n=\beta^m$, it makes no sense to compare an element in $G$ to a coset.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some correct ideas but it is pretty messy. I propose the following:

$$H\;\text{ is cyclic}\;\implies H=\langle h\rangle\;,\;\;G/H \text{ is cyclic}\;\implies G/H=\langle gH\rangle\,,\,\,g\in G$$

And now: for any $\;x\in G\;$ there exists a  $\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ s.t. that 
$$\;x=g^kh'\in g^kH=\left(gH\right)^k\in G/H\;,\;\;h'\in H\;$$

and there's also some $\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ such that $\;h'=h^m\;$...finish now the argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think your proof is unnecessarily complicated,  though you did get your hands on the generators.

It seems $G=\langle \alpha, \beta\mid \alpha^m,\beta^n\rangle $, where $\langle \alpha \rangle =H$, $\langle \beta\rangle =G/H$, $m=\mid H\mid$ and $n=\mid G/H\mid$, should be pretty easy to prove.   For, every element  $g\in G$ is in some coset $\beta^k\langle \alpha \rangle $.  Thus $g=\beta^k\alpha^l$ for some $k,l\in\Bbb Z$.